# how to implement the example of letter 'A' in the wiki of nonlinear dimensionality reduction

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

When I read the wiki of nonlinear dimensionality reduction(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction), I found the interesting example of letter 'A', so I want to implement it using python, but I get some problems here. The code I use to generate the data is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for scale in range(15):
    for rot in range(50):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2.05),facecolor='w')
    ax=plt.axes([0,0,1,1],frameon=False,xticks=[],yticks=[])    
    ax.text(0.5,0.5,'A',fontsize=150-scale*5,family='Times New Roman',
            fontdict={'ha':'center', 'va':'center'},
            rotation=rot*3.6)
    fig.savefig('./letterA/'+str(scale)+'s_r'+str(rot)+'.png',dpi=16)
```

Then I use pca and manifold sculpting in the Waffles packages to do dimensionality reduction, but I get different results from the figure on the wiki.

Comment: May I ask which python package can be used to perform manifold sculpting?